# My selenium python code unable to locate links in the webpage

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

My `selenium` python code is unable to locate links in the webpage.

I have two questions related to the following code -

1. I cannot even login to the webpage if I do not mention `login:password` in the `self.base_url` (please see admin:admin).

   It is to be noted that this web page throws a pop up for username and password. I could only login to it as mentioned above.

   Is there a way where I need not mention user id and password in the `self.base_url`?
2. After I manage to login to the webpage, I could not click on any of the links on the webpage. Please see the error which I am getting
   `C:\Python27>python.exe test2.py`

`ERROR: test_2 (__main__.Test2)`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 22, in test_2
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Devices").click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 282, in find_element_by_link_text
return self.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value=link_text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 712, in find_element
{'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Devices"}
Stacktrace:
at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///c:/users/saurabht/appdata/local/temp/tmpmvm1dg/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10723)
at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///c:/users/saurabht/appdata/local/temp/tmpmvm1dg/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:623)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 47.509s

FAILED (errors=1)

-----------------------------
```

Selenium script;

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re

class Test2(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "http://admin:admin@172.22.1.124/acs/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_2(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/")
        time.sleep(15)
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Devices").click()
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("364114").click()


    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException as e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException as e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(exit=False)
```

Comment: Updated the formatting so that things are easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you say that the web page throws in a **pop up**, and if the **pop up** is **Web Based** then you would most likely need to switch between windows. It is most likely that the focus is not on the the main web page and thats the reason you are unable to find any elements within it. Please look at how to switch between windows [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: I did try to switch windows also tried switch frames but no success. However, this is the issue which I already dealt with by using - self.base_url = "http://admin:admin@172.22.1.124/acs/". My primary concern now is that I after I am logged in, I could not find any elements on the web page.